Is there no free healing in the Chasm?
All the teleportation in the Chasm seems to come from Teleport Waypoints, which doesn't heal the party unlike Shrines of the Seven.
Is there no free healing in the Chasm, and I have to leave in order to heal without having a healer character nor spending food?
